# Select statement with where clause subquery returning multiple rows to be checked if contained in another subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

This is roughly what I have been trying to do and I can not seem to figure out how to get it to work.

```
SELECT a.name FROM tableA a, TableB b
WHERE a.key = b.key
AND (SELECT b.values FROM tableA a, TableB b
     WHERE a.key = b.key
     AND a.name = Prime_Key) IN 
     (SELECT b.values FROM tableA a, TableB b WHERE a.key = b.key)
```

I have two tables with a one to many relationship from tableA to tableB. I need a select that find all the values from tableB for a specific name in tableA and then finds all the names that also are associated with all the values. So the final output will be a list of names that have a link to all of the values that the given Prime_Key has.

A bit of sample data would be:

tableA:

```
name    key
Bob     1
Alice   2
Mark    3
Jill    4
Luke    5
```

and tableB:

```
key value
1   short
1   boy
2   tall
2   girl
2   blond
3   short
3   brownhair
3   boy
3   golf
4   girl
5   golf
5   boy
5   brownhair
```

So if I were to replace Prim_Key with `Bob`, the results would be `Mark`as he has both values short and boy. Likewise if Prim_Key was `Mark` there would be no return as no one else has all the values that he does

Comment: This looks like you are overcomplicating the problem.  Can you show us sample input and output data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery joins + counting matches to achieve your results:

```
SELECT 
    person_name, 
    sum(total_match) total_matches, 
    num_attributes

FROM (

    SELECT 
        search_name,
        search_value, 
        num_attributes, 
        person_name, 
        sum(is_match) total_match
    FROM (

        SELECT
            search_subject.name as search_name,
            search_subject.value as search_value,
            search_subject.total_attributes as num_attributes,
            people.name as person_name,
            people.value as person_value,
            IF(search_subject.value=people.value,1,0) as is_match

        FROM (

            SELECT 
                name, 
                value, 
                total_attributes
            FROM tablea
            JOIN tableb USING(`key`)
            JOIN (

                SELECT count(*) total_attributes
                FROM tablea
                JOIN tableb using(`key`)
                WHERE name = 'Bob'

            ) attributes_count
            WHERE name = 'Bob'

        ) search_subject

        JOIN (

            SELECT  
                name, 
                value
            FROM tablea
            JOIN tableb using(`key`)

        ) people ON ( search_subject.name <> people.name)

    ) x
    GROUP BY search_name, search_value, person_name

) y
GROUP BY person_name
HAVING total_matches = num_attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I used GROUP_CONCAT function to group values for each key into one and, at the mean time, created the pattern for like clause.

```
SELECT key, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE ORDER BY VALUE DESC SEPARATOR '%' ) AS myValues
FROM tableB
GROUP BY key;
```

The result would be sth like this:

```
key value
1   boy%short
2   blond%girl%tall
3   boy%brownhair%golf%short
4   girl
5   boy%brownhair%golf
```

Then create the like query to get the result. For simplicity, you can create a view using:

```
CREATE VIEW table_ab AS (SELECT key, GROUP_CONCAT(VALUE ORDER BY VALUE DESC SEPARATOR '%' ) AS myValues
FROM tableB
GROUP BY key);
```

Finally you can get the result by:

```
SELECT 
  t2.name 
FROM
table_ab t1 
  LEFT JOIN test_a t2 
ON t1.key = t2.key
WHERE t1.myvalues LIKE 
 (SELECT myvalues FROM table_ab WHERE key = (SELECT key FROM test_a a WHERE a.name = 'Bob')) AND t2.name != 'Bob'
```